# Taylor Expansion $\log(\frac{1+z}{1-z})$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

Taylor Expansion of $\log(\frac{1+z}{1-z})$ around $z=0$

But $\log(1+z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{z^n}{n}$

How can I continue from here?

Comment: You could use the fact that $\log(a/b) = \log(a)- \log(b)$.

Comment: An almost identical question was asked earlier today, except it used $x$ instead of $z$.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the fact that $\log(\frac{1+z}{1-z}) = \log(1+z) - \log(1-z)$, then do the Taylor expansion of each of these terms separately and then take the difference.